# Reduce Foreach Loop in C#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I've got a category model like:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_CATEGORY_TITLE { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_CATEGORY_URL { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_CATEGORY_BANNER_URL { get; set; }
    public bool IS_ACTIVE { get; set; }
    public List<ProductCategory> subCategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

I want to find subcategories that belong to the category and find subcategories that belong each one of these subcategories using a `foreach` loop. So I use this code:

```
foreach (var category in cat.categoriesList)
{
    category.subCategoryList = new List<ProductCategory>();
    category.subCategoryList =
        GetSubProductCategoryByMainCategory(category.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID.ToString());
    foreach (var sub in category.subCategoryList)
    {
        sub.subCategoryList =
            GetSubProductCategoryByMainCategory(sub.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID.ToString());
    }
}
```

But it takes a long time. Is there any way to make this faster?

Comment: This is too incomplete to help you. Where does the outer list you iterate over come from? What does GetSubProductCategoryByMainCategory do, and how? 
(should be (GetSubProductCategoriesByMainCategory?)

Comment: @Magnus The function goes to database and get  subcategories by category id.In my opinion, this GetSubProductCategoryByMainCategory function does not take much time. Foreach loops takes a lot of time.Can the recursive function help with this?

Comment: @C.Ergin So for 10 categories with 10 subcategories each that's  100 DB calls ?

Comment: That sounds like potentially a lot of database roundtrips. Could you do it with fewer or a single query, e.g, using entity framework and AutoMapper? You should probably do some benchmarking/measurements to find out what takes time.

Comment: Agreed with @Magnus. I guess you could also load all categories from the DB and map them locally.

Comment: If I get all categories in a single query and then mapping on that list,it will speed up? I use 2 foreach loops anyway.

Comment: Foreach loops are as fast as they come, it is what you do in them that matters. Each call to GetSubProductCategoryByMainCategory might not take long, but you make a lot of them. Recursion typically does not help with performance but with algorithm complexity. From what you told us I see no reason it would help here.

Comment: Yes, getting all categories in one go and use that for lookup as dimitar.d suggests is likely to help. But to be sure you need to test.

Comment: Okay guys thanks to you for help, I will apply your suggestions and give you feedback on it.

Comment: Guys as you say, db query takes a lot of time.One of them not takes much but for 12  maincategories there are +100 DB calls and it takes a lot of time.So I get all cat list in a single query and map them it speed up.